# Xamarin.Forms: How to center views using Relative Layout? `Width` and `Height` return -1

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When trying to use the `Height` and `Width` properties of a control in Xamarin.Forms, both return -1, and it causes the Relative Layout to appear off-centered on the screen.

```
var mainLayout = new RelativeLayout();

//Add the Switch to the center of the screen
mainLayout.Children.Add(mySwitch,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - mySwitch.Width / 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height / 2 - mySwitch.Height / 2));

//Add a Label below the switch
mainLayout.Children.Add(switchLabel,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - switchLabel.Width / 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToView(mySwitch, (parent, view) => view.Y + mySwitch.Height + 10));

Content = mainLayout;
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Why does Xamarin.Forms return -1 for `Height` and `Width`?

Xamarin.Forms returns -1 as the default value for these properties, and it remains -1 until Xamarin.Forms creates the native control, e.g. UIButton, and adds that native control to the layout.

In this link, you can see the Xamarin.Forms source code returning `-1` as the default value:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/VisualElement.cs

## Best Way to Use Relative Layouts to Constrain Views

### Option 1: Local Functions (Requires C# 7.0 or higher)

Use a [Local Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions) to dynamically retrieve the `Width` and `Height` properties

```
var mainLayout = new RelativeLayout();

//Add the Switch to the center of the screen
mainLayout.Children.Add(mySwitch,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - getWidth(parent, mySwitch)/ 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height / 2 - getHeight(parent, mySwitch) / 2));

//Add a Label below the switch
mainLayout.Children.Add(switchLabel,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - getWidth(parent, switchLabel) / 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToView(mySwitch, (parent, view) => view.Y + getHeight(parent, mySwitch) + 10));

Content = mainLayout;

static double getWidth(RelativeLayout parent, View view) => view?.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Width ?? -1;
static double getHeight(RelativeLayout parent, View view) => view?.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Height ?? -1;
```

### Option 2: `Func<RelativeLayout, double>`

Use a `Func` to dynamically retrieve the `Width` and `Height` properties

```
var mainLayout = new RelativeLayout();

Func<RelativeLayout, double> getSwitchWidth = (parent) => mySwitch.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Width;
Func<RelativeLayout, double> getSwitchHeight = (parent) => mySwitch.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Height;
Func<RelativeLayout, double> getLabelWidth = (parent) => switchLabel.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Width;
Func<RelativeLayout, double> getLabelHeight = (parent) => switchLabel.Measure(parent.Width, parent.Height).Request.Height;

//Add the Switch to the center of the screen
mainLayout.Children.Add(mySwitch,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - getSwitchWidth(parent)/ 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height / 2 - getSwitchHeight(parent) / 2));

//Add a Label below the switch
mainLayout.Children.Add(switchLabel,
    Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - getLabelWidth(parent) / 2),
    Constraint.RelativeToView(mySwitch, (parent, view) => view.Y + getSwitchHeight(parent) + 10));

Content = mainLayout;
```

[image]

Thanks to [@BrewMate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5166245/brewmate) for teaching me this trick!

Comment: This is also great for centering Labels containing dynamic text! As the text increases/decreases in size, the Relative Layout will automatically recalculate its width and keep the Label centered!

Comment: The answer by CaptainXamtastic in the Xamarin Forms also does a great job explaining this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22902/how-to-add-a-label-to-a-relative-layout-and-center-it-horizontally

Comment: Is there a way to do this in XAML?

Comment: How can I do this in xaml ? Thank you !