# Xamarin Forms how to fill Image view horizontal and expand vertically?

Tags: image, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a problem making my **ImageButton**'s width fixed and the **Height** will be changed with the size of the image that I use in the **ImageButton**, I use the **ImageButton** multiple times in a **Scrollview**, I use **Visual Studio** to create a **Cross-Platform App** using **Xamarin**, So what I used to solve my problem are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193754/xamarin-forms-image-size-mismatch?rq=1) and [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65902/how-do-i-fix-the-size-of-an-image), But I wasn't able to solve it using anything, And this is a picture that describes what I want:-
[image]

And please don't make it duplicate if there's answers for my question because I am new to ***Xamarin Forms*** And I didn't find any answer exactly to my question, And this is my code:-

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10"  OutlineColor="#fce9cc" Padding="4" Margin="15" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
       HasShadow="True" x:Name="ViewLayout" x:FieldModifier="public" BackgroundColor="Black">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="filmNameLabel_1"  HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White"
                   Margin="0,15,0,15"/>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <ImageButton x:Name="imageWidget_1" BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

First time I set the **StackLayout** or the parent of the **ImageButton**'s HeightRequest to a number and it would make the **ImageButton**'s **Height** a fixed number but I dont want that I want the **ImageButton**'s ***Height*** to change with the Image's size **Ratio** bye the width which is fixed next to 
the parent layout.

Comment: have you tried setting [Aspect="Fill"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.aspect?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: Yes, I also tried that.

Comment: @Azhy Clean project ,and rebuild it. Setting `Aspect="Fill" ` to try again.